# How to store deque value between function calls

Tags: c++, stl

**For example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

int func(int a){
  std::deque<int> obj;
  obj.push_back(a);
  for(std::deque<int>::iterator it = obj.begin(); it!=obj.end();++it)
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
  return 0;
}
int main()
{
  int x=2;

  func(x);
  func(x);
}
```

**output is :**

```
2  
2
```

so its mean that deque object destroy after reach end scope of func. And i cant do nothing with this, except return value or add to global scope?  No way to change behavior of this object with adding static to him or static pointer or something else? I mean that with pure C++ its look like :

```
int func(int a){
  static int *p = new int;
}
```

and value will be store between function calls but how to do same with stl containers i don't know.

Comment: Have you tried using static? What was the effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want it to be static, make it so:

```
static std::deque<int> obj;
```

although this is probably a bad idea: conceptually, you have hidden state in the program, and practically, there's a possibility of accessing the object after it's been destroyed. (You can fudge around the lifetime issues by using dynamic allocation and leaking the object, as demonstrated in Drax's answer, if you really want to go down this particular road of pain).

Better would be to encapsulate the state in a class. Then you can control exactly when it's created and destroyed, and have more than one instance if you like.

```
class thing {
public:
    int func(int a) {
        obj.push_back(a);
        // and print it
    }
private:
    std::deque<int> obj;
};

int main() {
    thing t;
    t.func(2);  // 2
    t.func(3);  // 2 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remember data between function calls, store it elsewhere, or as a last resort make it static.
So, either go with Mike Seymour's answer to make it a member of a class, or hold onto it in main, and pass it to the function, making sure you pass by reference if you wish to change it:

```
int func(int a, std::deque<int> & obj){
  //.. as you were
}
```

From main, make the data and pass it in:

```
int main()
{
  int x=2;
  std::deque<int> obj;

  func(x, obj);
  func(x, obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
int func(int a){
  static std::deque<int>* obj = new std::deque<int>;
  obj->push_back(a);
  for(std::deque<int>::iterator it = obj->begin(); it!=obj->end();++it)
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

But i'm not sure that's a good idea :)

Comment: Why use dynamic allocation for the deque?

Comment: @Agentlien Just to follow the example the OP gave with the `int`. When you are at the point of using static variables, "perfect conception" is not an issue anymore :)

Comment: Perhaps, but I would prefer to see a correct example, without memory leaks, in an answer which people may learn from.

Comment: @Agentlien: There's no "correct" answer for a non-trivial static object, just the choice between a leaking it, and potentially accessing it after destruction.

Comment: @MileSeymour How could it be accessed after destruction in this case? And how does dynamic allocation solve that?

Comment: @Agentlien: The static object is destroyed sometime after the end of `main`. The destructor of another static object, or a function registered with `atexit`, could call this function after that, resulting in access to the destroyed object. If you dynamically allocate it, then it will never be (automatically) destroyed.

Comment: @MikeSeymour So if I understand this correctly, the static object (now a pointer) will still be "destroyed" leading to undefined behaviour, but with great chances of working in practice?

Comment: @Agentlien: The pointer is a trivial type, so it isn't "destroyed" until its memory is released - which doesn't happen until the very end of the program. There's no possibility of accessing it after it's been "destroyed".